# Block Task.Run method until done

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I've got some methods that I need to run, one of them should run as a different Thread so I use a Task.Run with lambda, though I want the next method to start just after the Task finishes.

for example I want `LastJob()` will start after `MoreWork()` is done:

```
public void DoSomeWork()
{
    Task.Run(() => MoreWork());
    LastJob();
}
```

Comment: You can read about the `ContinueWith` method of `Task`, or even better - the keywords `async` and `await`. Great video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCW_eJA2FeY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `async` and `await` key words
[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

```
public async void DoSomeWork()
{
    await Task.Run(() => MoreWork());
    LastJob();
}
```

Comment: Use `async Task`, not `void`.

Comment: No problem. Ant P whats the problem with void? It will wait anyway

Comment: @Sag1v, exception handling. `async void` basically swallows all exceptions.

Comment: Well the question was how to wait :) jasnet in that link i posted you can see the Task<Tresult> example and more...

Answer (score 0):

Coy could use the `ContinueWith` method, like this:

```
public void DoSomeWork()
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => MoreWork());
    task.ContinueWith(() => LastJob()) ;
}
```